# PhpStorm warning expecting wrong thing

Tags: php, phpstorm

In one file I am creating a controller like this:

```
$controller = new typeController(true, $dbHandler, $repository);
```

and PhpStorm is highlighting the word 'true' saying 'Expected Repository, got bool'

The typeController construct is:

```
public function __construct($createSession=true, $con=false, Repository $repository) {
    parent::__construct($createSession, $con);
    $this->repository = $repository;
}
```

So why is it saying it should be Repository first and not bool? Why does the $dbHandler work fine, what am I missing?

EDIT:
Quick documentation says:

```
public function typeController::__construct($createSession=true, $con=false, Repository $repository) typeController
```

typeController constructor.
Parameters:

> bool $createSession
>
> bool $con
>
> classes\Repository $repository

Declared in:

`classes\types\typeController`

Comment: Probably because the default values are useless when they are not at the end

Comment: 1) Please show full signature of that method (preferably -- whole file) 2) Having default values for parameters that not at the end ... makes little sense 3) Place caret on that problematic line and invoke `View | Quick Documentation` -- post a screenshot of what PhpStorm thinks about that method.

Comment: All parameters with default values must come after all parameters with no default values.

Comment: Ok I added the quick documentation, also added all the construct. So I swapped repository and true around and it now works with no warnings. Thank-you!

Comment: You have invoked `Quick Documentation` for a wrong element -- I want to see what PhpStorm thinks about **method** (constructor in our case) and not about `true`. But since you have swapped the parameters in declaration already and it works for you now.. then I guess there is no more need for that (for what I have asked).

Comment: Sorry ive now added quick documentation for the __construct anyway. But yeah swapping them seams to have worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$repository` field has no default value and yet it is the last constructor argument. Since the other two have default values then `$repository` should come first like in the following:

```
public function __construct(Repository $repository, $createSession=true, $con=false)
```

That way you can initialize the controller like this:

```
$controller = new typeController($repository);
```

if you want to keep the default values, or like this:

```
$controller = new typeController($repository, true, $dbHandler);
```

if you want to override them.

You can't place a constructor argument without a default value, after a constructor argument that has a default value because a default argument can be ommitted during object instantiation